# How to prevent top cut off on using position absolute?

Tags: html, css

I have a modal that should always appear at the bottom of the page. But, whenever its height exceeds the screen height, its top region is cut off. I want to prevent that. Here is the simplified version of the code.

```
<div class="modal">Modal</div>

.modal{
  position: absolute;
  width: 440px;
  height:700px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}
```

Comment: If the modal is too big for the screen, what do you want to happen?

Comment: Use percentage for height instead of a hard pixel value. e.g. - height: 50%;

Comment: @gibberish The screen becomes scroll able. Like overflow:scroll.

Comment: @Lowkase I wish I could do that but designer is telling me to make it fixed height.

Comment: @gibberish Ok. But how can I create a modal with position relative. It should always appear over all the thing at the bottom right corner.

Comment: @gibberish On doing that, wont it push away the other content on the site? It is relative right?

Comment: Try with ``position: fixed`` and setting ``bottom: 0`` and ``left: 0``

Comment: @iamdev That's what I have done previously. When I set it to top:0, scroll bar appears. But when I set it to bottom:0 and if the height is less than the height of modal, top region is cut off.

Comment: @UnityHour that is the expected behaviour. You should not give more height to your modal than your viewport height. Maximum height you can set like this ``max-height: 100%``

Comment: @iamdev I know I am not supposed to do that. But it is the part of the design. That modal has many forms so no matter how much I shrink it is not going to get fit in small screen.

Comment: @iamdev The only thing that I want is whenever the modal exceeds the viewport height, I want to be able to scroll up.

Comment: @UnityHour if that is the case, you can use ``overflow-y: auto`` to your modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `max-height` is for. Add this to your modal styling:

```
max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
```

In this example I am subtracting the 20px that you are spacing from the bottom from the height of the screen (100vh). Feel free to adjust as needed.

If the height of your modal gets shorter than its content you need to add:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```